# SQL: Is it possible to 'group by' according to 'like' function's results?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, grouping, sql-like

I am using Oracle SQL and I want to group some different rows that 'like' function results. To elaborate with an example:

---

*Let's assume I have a table MESA with one of the columns is a huge string. And I am counting the number of rows matching particular patterns:*

```
SELECT m.str, count(*)
FROM MESA m
WHERE m.str LIKE '%FRUIT%'
AND (m.str LIKE '%APPLE%' OR m.str LIKE '%ORANGE%')
```

*So let's assume the result of this query is:*

FRUIT..afsafafasfa...RED_APPLE      20

FRUIT..afsafafasfa...YELLOW_APPLE   12

FRUIT..afsafafasfa...GREEN_APPLE     3

FRUIT..afsafafasfa...PURPLE_ORANGE   4

FRUIT..afsafafasfa...RED_ORANGE     45

*But I want my results to be:*

APPLE      35

ORANGE     49

---

Is this possible to do? If so, how so? : )

Comments and code snippets are much appreciated.

PS: Of course the query and the results are more complicated than the above example. I just wrote it like for the sake of simplicity to explain.

Cheers..

Comment: How about strings like that: 'FRUIT..afsafafasfa...ORANGE_APPLE"? ;)

Comment: Yes, that's a good remark. For my case, it's not very likely to have such strings. I guess it depends on the order of cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure:

```
WITH Fruits AS (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
           WHEN m.str LIKE '%APPLE%' THEN 'Apple'
           WHEN m.str LIKE '%ORANGE%' THEN 'Orange' 
        END AS FruitType           
    FROM MESA m
    WHERE m.str LIKE '%FRUIT%')
SELECT FruitType, COUNT(*) 
FROM Fruits
WHERE FruitType IN ('Apple', 'Orange')
GROUP BY FruitType;
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I love this WITH thingie : )

Answer (score 2):

Another variant of David Markle answer:

```
SELECT 
  fruit_name,
  count(1)  as fruit_count
FROM (
  SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN m.str LIKE '%APPLE%' THEN 'Apple'
      WHEN m.str LIKE '%ORANGE%' THEN 'Orange' 
    END                                         as fruit_name
  FROM 
    MESA m
  WHERE 
    m.str LIKE '%FRUIT%'
    AND 
    (m.str LIKE '%APPLE%' OR m.str LIKE '%ORANGE%')
)
GROUP BY 
  fruit_name
```

Same thing, but only 1 CASE required, which simplifies support ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) AS 'Apples'
FROM MESA m
WHERE m.str LIKE '%FRUIT%'
AND m.str LIKE '%APPLE%'

SELECT count(*) AS 'Oranges'
FROM MESA m
WHERE m.str LIKE '%FRUIT%'
AND m.str LIKE '%ORANGE%'
```

Would that work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer JNKyle. I've also thought about this but Dave's answer is more appropriate for my case (as I have lots of groups to be made)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT Fruit,
      SUM(counter)
 FROM ( SELECT CASE 
                   WHEN m.str LIKE '%APPLE%'
                       THEN 'APPLE'
                   ELSE 'ORANGE'
               END AS Fruit
               COUNT(*) AS counter
          FROM MESA m 
         WHERE m.str LIKE '%FRUIT%' 
           AND (m.str LIKE '%APPLE%' OR m.str LIKE '%ORANGE%')
         GROUP BY m.str
      )
GROUP BY Fruit
```

Comment: you can't use count(*) without grouping clause ... (look at internal select)

Comment: @ThinkJet- Sorry, I thought I did have a GROUP BY in the internal SELECT

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way -- only requires a single change to add additional types of fruit.

```
WITH fruits AS (
  SELECT 'APPLE' fruit FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ORANGE' fruit FROM DUAL
)
SELECT fruit, count(*)
FROM MESA m, fruits
WHERE m.str LIKE '%FRUIT%'
AND m.str LIKE '%' || fruits.fruit || '%'
GROUP BY fruit
```

If your strings are reliably in the format you showed in your sample data, I would consider changing the predicate to one condition, `WHERE m.str LIKE 'FRUIT%' || fruits.fruit ||'%'`.